# Local Jekyll Repository Clone shows different output from Github hosted page

Tags: github, static, jekyll

New to Jekyll. Have created and hosted a site via github for jekyll. Tried to clone the repo and serve it locally. Problem is that some pages show differently from the online hosted version. If you look at the site I created online:

http://taijisoce.com/

and click (excuse the immaturity) "Jamie is the butthole now its online" you can see it takes you to another well formatted page.

However when I tried to clone it to my local repository (I am on windows) and serve the site the homepage looks alright. But when I click the above link it just takes me to a plaintext line that says "does this work? Can I put this text and make it make sense?" no formatting no css etc.

Repo: https://github.com/themallardcomplexion/themallardcomplexion.github.io

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you link to the GitHub repo?

Comment: Yes sorry I should have done that: https://github.com/themallardcomplexion/themallardcomplexion.github.io

Answer (score 0):

Looking into this I added YML front matter to my post and tried to serve again. With the front matter entered it formatted correctly.

I just dont understand how Github didnt require front matter for it to format correctly.